# UWP Unit Tests Don't Run from MSIX

Tags: uwp, mstest, vstest, appx, msix

We've changed the minimum target version of our app (and unit test app) to 1809 (17763) and now MSBuild generates MSIX files instead of APPX files. VSTest doesn't seem to like it...

[image: run against msix]

I've tried both MSIX and MSIXBUNDLE but both have the same results. The app is trusted, can be installed and run, but it doesn't find and run the tests! So then I used the `/diag:<log-path>` parameter to get detailed logs and I found this error:

```
No test discoverer is registered to perform discovery for the type of test source 'C:\AppPackages\...\*.msixbundle'. Register a test discoverer for this source type and try again.
```

So it seems this is not supported... Is there a way I can force MSBuild to build an appx instead of msix? Or is there a way to get this supported?

Comment: I created this issue on GitHub, but I would still like a workaround.
https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/2476

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but I tried just renaming the `<test-file>.msix` extension to `<test-file>.appx` and then running the tests against that, and...

**It worked!**